# Attribute reference in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some doubts regarding attribute reference in Python. I used to think attribute reference as in `instance.attribute` is bottom-up approach.
First that attribute is looked up in instance dictionary. But I was reading some article where it claims that attribute lookup is top-down approach i.e. when an attribute is referenced, `Class.__getattribute__` is called as first step. Here `instance` is the instance of class `Class`

My question is (considering class may contain a data descriptor or non data descriptor)

1. Is attribute reference a bottom-up or top down
2. Looks like both will give similar results. Am I correct here?

Answer (score 0):

> Is attribute reference a bottom-up or top down

I wouldn't classify it as bottom-up or top-down. Pythons `__getattribute__` first searches in the class dictionary in order to first find data descriptors if they exist, it then also searches the instance dictionary for instance variables (if no data descriptors have been found).

> Looks like both will give similar results

No, if it was strictly bottom-up (instance first) then an instance variable with the same name as a data descriptor would mask it.

If it was top-down then a non-data descriptor with the same name as an instance variable would mask it.